# How to access element inside ControlTemplate?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a requirement like `ActivityIndicator` will appear while API call is executing. This will same for all the pages. so I have created BasePage and put activity indicator in the `BasePage.xaml`.

**BasePage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
x:Class="XamarinFormDemo.Base.BasePage"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

<ContentPage.ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Name="baseTemplate">

        <AbsoluteLayout
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <ContentPresenter AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />

            <StackLayout
                x:Name="stackProgress"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                BackgroundColor="#8C000000"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                IsVisible="False"
                Orientation="Vertical"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                <ActivityIndicator
                    x:Name="indicatorProgress"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    IsRunning="True"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Color="White" />
            </StackLayout>

        </AbsoluteLayout>

    </ControlTemplate>

</ContentPage.ControlTemplate>

</ContentPage>
```

I have created few methods to handle ActivityIndicator status like visible and Invisible when needed.

**BasePage.xaml.cs**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class BasePage : ContentPage
{

public BasePage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}


/*
 * Show progress dialog 
 */
public void ShowProgress()
{

    if (!stackProgress.IsVisible)
    {
        stackProgress.IsVisible = true;
    }

}

/*
 * Hide progress dialog
 */
public void HideProgress()
{

    stackProgress.IsVisible = false;

  }

}
```

Now I have created LoginPage.xaml and add BasePage as root control.so that I can access indicator. same thing I have done for other pages.

**LoginPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<base:BasePage
x:Class="XamarinFormDemo.MainPage"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:base="clr-namespace:XamarinFormDemo.Base"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinFormDemo.Controls"
BackgroundColor="#2b3d53"
NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">

<ScrollView>

    <StackLayout
        Padding="24"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        Orientation="Vertical"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <Image
            Margin="0,32,0,32"
            HeightRequest="100"
            Source="ai_logo.jpg"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            WidthRequest="100" />

        <local:CustomEntry
            x:Name="entryEmail"
            Margin="0,0,0,8"
            DrawableImage="email_hover_icon"
            FontSize="Small"
            IsSpellCheckEnabled="False"
            Keyboard="Email"
            Placeholder="Email"
            PlaceholderColor="Gray"
            Text="peter@klaven.com"
            TextColor="Black" />

        <local:CustomEntry
            x:Name="entryPassword"
            Margin="0,0,0,8"
            DrawableImage="password_hover_icon"
            FontSize="Small"
            IsPassword="True"
            IsSpellCheckEnabled="False"
            Placeholder="Password"
            PlaceholderColor="Gray"
            Text="cityslicka"
            TextColor="Black" />

        <Button
            x:Name="buttonLogin"
            Margin="0,16,0,16"
            BackgroundColor="#009999"
            Clicked="ButtonLogin_ClickedAsync"
            FontSize="Small"
            Text="Login"
            TextColor="White" />

        <Label
            FontSize="Small"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Text="OR"
            TextColor="White" />

        <Button
            x:Name="buttonSignUp"
            Margin="0,16,0,16"
            BackgroundColor="#009999"
            Clicked="NavigateToSignUp"
            FontSize="Small"
            Text="SignUp"
            TextColor="White" />

    </StackLayout>

</ScrollView>
</base:BasePage>
```

In **LoginPage.xaml.cs** file I have code for making a call for login and handling activity indicator using `ShowProgress();` and `HideProgress();`
these methods belong to **BasePage.xaml.cs**.

**LoginPage.xaml.cs**

```
    namespace XamarinFormDemo
    {
    public partial class MainPage : BasePage
    {
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    private async Task ButtonLogin_ClickedAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            ShowProgress();

           // API Call

            HideProgress();

    }
  }    
}
```

I want output like below. Please have a look into images.

[View should be like this when the ActivityIndicator is hidden](https://ibb.co/dz1FiU)

[View should be like this when calling API](https://ibb.co/gA9J3U)

The issue is, I am not able to access "stackProgress" in code behind. because it is `ControlTemplate`. it is saying that

> The name "stackProgress" does not exist in the current context.

Is there any other way to achieve the same thing? or

Can someone tell me what I have done wrong?

How can I fix it?

Comment: I think the question here is: what are you trying to achieve? Because I suspect you might be approaching this the wrong way :-)

Comment: @GeraldVersluis, I want to show an indicator while API processing. So I have created BasePage and put `ActivityIndicator`inside the page. Now, whenever I create the new page I will extend `xaml` and `cs` file base BasePage. so I can access all the controls from `BasePage`. But the issue is I am not able to access controls inside `ControlTemplate`. Any idea how can i fix this?

Comment: Ok, but why are you putting it in a `ControlTemplate` then?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis, Because it does not work outside ControlTemplate. do you have any idea how can I achieve the same thing without `ControlTemplate`?

Comment: Instead of ControlTemplate try to use ConentView.

Comment: @SrustiThakkar, I have tried both the ways but it is not working. In content view Indicator does not appear. Can you please modify my XAML if you know right way?

Comment: I have added XAML. Please try and let me know it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code please :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<ContentPage
 x:Class="XamarinFormDemo.Base.BasePage"
 xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

<ContentPage.Content>           
        <AbsoluteLayout
            x:Name="dd"               
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">               
            <ContentView x:Name="baseTemplate">
                <StackLayout 
                x:Name="stackProgress"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                BackgroundColor="#8C000000"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"                    
                Orientation="Vertical"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">                       
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentView>
            <StackLayout Padding="12" x:Name="DisplayLoading" 
             IsVisible="False"
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,-1,-1">
            <ActivityIndicator Color="#d7813e" IsRunning="True"/>
            <Label Text="Loading..." TextColor="#d7813e" FontSize="Small"/>
        </StackLayout>                
<ContentPage.Content>
```

Try CS Code like :

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class BasePage : ContentPage
{ 
    public BasePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /*
     * Show progress dialog 
     */
    public void ShowProgress()
    {    
        DisplayLoading.IsVisible = true;
    }

    /*
     * Hide progress dialog
     */
    public void HideProgress()
    {    
         DisplayLoading.IsVisible = false;    
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: `ActivityIndicator` does not show. Please check my updated question. You will have an idea what i want.

Comment: I have made minor change please try once.

Comment: Can you please add your activity indicator show/ hide code?

Comment: I have added code please try once both XAML And cs file.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use [TemplateBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/template-binding).

So basically you can reuse [IsBusy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.isbusy?view=xamarin-forms) property - in your control-template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Name="baseTemplate">
    <AbsoluteLayout ..>
        <ContentPresenter AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
        <StackLayout
            x:Name="stackProgress"
            ...
            IsVisible="{TemplateBinding IsBusy}"
            ...>

            <ActivityIndicator
                ...
                IsRunning="{TemplateBinding IsBusy}"
                IsVisible="{TemplateBinding IsBusy}"
                Color="White" />
        </StackLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Now you can either bind this `IsBusy` property using MVVM, or update your methods in code-behind:

```
/*
 * Show progress dialog 
 */
public void ShowProgress()
{
    if (!IsBusy)
    {
        IsBusy = false;
    }
}

/*
 * Hide progress dialog
 */
public void HideProgress()
{
    IsBusy = false;
}
```

Comment: The solution is not working. The indicator does not show.

Comment: Try setting the `HeightRequest` and `WidthRequest` on the `ActivitiyIndicator`. `AbsoluteLayout` flags won't work as the control in now embedded inside the `StackLayout` and make sure to update the `IsVisible` property on `StackLayout` too